# Given the norm of a Gaussian integer, how to find the original Gaussian integer?

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

For $p= a + bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, its norm is $$N(p) = (a + bi)(a - bi) = a^2 + b^2.$$ 
For example, $N(2+7i) = 2^2+7^2 = 4+49 = 53$. How to find $2+7i$ from $53$? Is there any method?

Comment: I believe $\pm2 \pm 7i$ and $\pm7 \pm 2i$ all have the same norm.

Comment: The equation $a^2+b^2=N$ will in general have *multiple* solutions, even up to associates and conjugates in the Gaussian integers. ([See also](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html).) Predictably, one can just run a brute-force search, perhaps with some obvious congruence-based modifications. Dunno about state-of-the-art methods for actually finding explicit representations of $N$ as a sum of two squares though. (Tangent: was this open-ended question really asked as such in an actual math contest, as suggested by the tag?)

Comment: You can use Jacobsthal sums

Comment: Not only that $\,\pm a\pm bi\,,\,\pm b\pm ai\;$ have the same norm, but there also are numbers which are the norm of very different Gaussian integers: for example $\,4,225\,$ can fit for $$\pm 65\,,\,\pm65i\,,\,\pm15\pm20i\,,\,\pm20\pm15i\,,\,\pm16\pm63i\,,\,\pm63\pm16i\,,\ldots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way described in Jacobsthal's "Über eine Darstellung der Primzahlen der Form $4n+1$", see [link](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0132&DMDID=dmdlog17&LOGID=log17&PHYSID=phys245#navi), section $2$.

Find any quadratic rest $r$ modulo your prime $p \equiv 1 (4)$; then, a choice for $a$ is $$a = \sum_{m=1}^{(p-1)/2} \Big(\frac{m}{p}\Big) \Big(\frac{m^2 + r}{p}\Big).$$

The above are Legendre symbols. For example, when we calculate this for $p = 53$, taking $r=1$, we get $a = 7$ - from this it is easy to find $53 = 7^2 + 2^2.$

Another example, with $p=29$ and $r=1$: we get $a=-5$, corresponding to $29 = 5^2 + 2^2.$

Comment: A cool formula, but is this faster than trying all possible values of $a$ in the range $1\le a<\sqrt p$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think it would be more efficient, though maybe less satisfying, to guess-and-check as you say. I wanted to mention this as a "closed-form" expression for the original Gaussian integer. There is a similar expression for (a choice of) $b$ in the article, but it is even more difficult to evaluate.

Comment: @Cocopuffu thanks.

Comment: @Cocopuffs can we take any velue of r?

Comment: plz give some link of Jacobsthal sums, so that i can understand it better.

Comment: @user84853 Hi, they seem to be described the best in the link I gave. I remember reading about them I think in Bundschuh's book Einführung in die Zahlentheorie. I don't have an English language reference.

Comment: @Cocopuffs hey,but when i calculate for p=29, taking r=1 value of a comes to be 13.2... As m vary from 1-14.

Comment: @user84853 "$m$ over $p$" is a Legendre symbol and not division. It takes values $0$ or $\pm 1$, so $a$ will always be an integer.

Comment: @Cocopuffs Legendre symbol give value 0,+1,-1 as "m mod p", that is applied in Jacobsthal sums in last step when we get value in terms of x/y.so how we get value of $a$ as other int like -5 when p=29, it need to be 0,+1,-1.

Comment: @user84853 It's a sum over $0$s and $\pm 1$s. It can be $-5$.