# Find any or all Lipschitz quaternions corresponding to a given quaternion norm

Tags: quaternions, quadratic-residues, gaussian-integers

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/435495/809113), in response to the question "How to find $2+7$ from $53$?", user [@Cocopuffs](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32943/cocopuffs) provided a reference to a Jacobsthal sum, which enables obtaining a Gaussian integer, based on a given Gaussian integer prime norm:

> There is a way described in Jacobsthal's "Über eine Darstellung der Primzahlen der Form $4n+1$", see [link][1], section $2$.
> Find any quadratic rest $r$ modulo your prime $p \equiv 1 (4)$; then, a choice for $a$ is $$a = \sum_{m=1}^{(p-1)/2} \Big(\frac{m}{p}\Big) \Big(\frac{m^2 + r}{p}\Big).$$
> The above are Legendre symbols. For example, when we calculate this for $p = 53$, taking $r=1$, we get $a = 7$ - from this it is easy to find $53 = 7^2 + 2^2.$

Lipschitz quaternions are quaternions whose components are all integers:
$$L=\{a+bi+cj+dk \in \mathbb{H} | a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Do there exist any sums (Jacobsthal or otherwise), which enable obtaining a Lipschitz quaternion (or the full set of quaternions) corresponding to a given (prime or otherwise) quaternion norm?

More generally, are there any non-brute-force methods (that is enumerating all possible combinations of integers up to a given point and checking each sum individually) which produce the desired result (finding any or all Lipschitz quaternions, corresponding to a given norm or category of norms)?

Comment: First you can reduce to primes dividing your number.  Then you can do brute force on those.  Or for $p$'s that are 1 mod 4 or not 7 mod 8, you can check for representations as sums of 2 or 3 squares.  Is this approach really that bad?

Comment: @Kimball, thank you for your comment! Could you please elaborate a bit on your second sentence, namely "Or for 's that are 1 mod 4 or not 7 mod 8, you can check for representations as sums of 2 or 3 squares."?
Is the suggestion to perform the checks (for sums of 2 or 3 squares) in a brute-force manner (since I am not familiar with a non-brute-force way of checking for 3 squares), whilst assuming $0^{2}$ for the remaining components?

Comment: Basically.  I don't know if that's more efficient than not assuming some components are 0 for such primes, but my impression was you liked the Jacobsthal sum approach for 2 squares, so you can use that some of the time.  Probably what I would do is dynamically build tables of sums of 1, 2, 3 and 4 squares using small values of your variables.  (Okay, really I'd just use Magma to find all vectors of small norms.)

Comment: @Kimball, I get now what you meant - thank you very much for the follow-up clarification!

Comment: It's indeed an improvement upon a "bare" brute-force search, but I'm more interested in whether there exist any sums that are directly applicable to quaternions.